# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Trying to run angular 4 app on Chrome in AWS EC2 VM Windows Server 2016, it blocks the downloading of vendor.bundle.js, there is also one more error "can not read property 'call' of undefined" in inline.bundle.js

After refresh it works. noticed this issue only in incognito chrome first time loading 
[snapshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NiOW.jpg)

[Error at line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV7ST.jpg) is modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, **webpack_require**)

Comment: `can not read property 'call' of undefined` is an error in your code. please show the relevant code snippet

Comment: [Error at line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV7ST.jpg) is `modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__)`